A problem about treating the unknown in nonlinear term in PDE as new variable and integrate it.
For example, if we have a bounded domain $\Omega$ whose volume is $1$, and on $\Omega$ I have a PDE:
$$
\Delta u + \frac{f(u)}{\int_\Omega f(u) dx}=0,
$$
of course it can be denoted as
$$
\Delta u + F(u)=0,
$$
because $\frac{f(u)}{\int_{\Omega} f(u) d x}$ is a function about $u$.
But now I want to do the integration:
$$\int_0^u F(s) ds.$$
Then I become very confused, if I treat $u$ as a new variable, then it will be independent on $x$, then $$
\frac{f(u)}{\int_{\Omega} f(u) d x}
$$ must always be $1$, where did I misunderstood?

The statement $$F(u) = \frac{f(u)}{\int_\Omega f(u) , dx }$$ with $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is not correct. For this to be true we must have that $F(u(x_0))$ with $x_0$ fixed depends only on the value of $u(x_0)$ i.e. any perturbation $u_\varepsilon$ of $u$ with $u_\varepsilon(x_0)=u(x_0)$ should satisfy $F(u_\varepsilon(x_0))=F(u(x_0))$. This is not the case here

Instead, you can think of $F$ as an operator acting on $u$, but then it doesn't make sense to integrate $F$

$F: H\to \mathbb{R}$ is a functional not a function where $H$ is some appropriate function space $u$ is in (Sobolev, Besov, Schauder, whatever), this means that $\displaystyle\int_0^u F(s) ds$ is not well-defined because the direct independent variable of $F(\cdot)$ is a function not a scalar value.
BTW: $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega} F(u)\, dx$ is indeed $1$.
